# How to resolve XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: apache-poi

Code outline of Test annotation:

```
void test() throws Exception{
        String filePath = System.setProperty("user.dir", "https://d.docs.live.net/12e57c5f83beb2a2/Documents/Book1.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum();
                
    }
```

I'm trying to read the data from an xlsx file and that when I'm trying to create an Instance of the XSSFWorkbook, the compiler says

"- XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type"

Please help me how to solve this issue. It Would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Imported the below, will solve your issue.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
```

Comment: Hi @Akzy I've tried importing the above mentioned. It says 

the import org.apache.poi cannot be resolved
the import org.apache.poi cannot be resolved

Could you please tell me if there is anything I need to import yet ?? or am I missing on something ??

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the Apache POI library ? If not use this link to download https://poi.apache.org/download.html . OR If you are using Maven, make sure you have added the Apache POI dependency to your project's build file.